# "Invalid Form Template" Error - InfoPath 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server, infopath, custom-list, list-form, infopath-data-connections

I've configured Infopath Forms Services in SharePoint Central Administration but cannot get it to talk to SharePoint.

I get the

> Invalid Form Template

error every time I run the Design checker.

Even when simply loading a default Custom List form from SharePoint and making no changes. The "expanded" error message is:

> An unexpected error has occurred while verifying the form template

I hope you can help.

Answer (score 0):

How did you configure InfoPath in CA?

Is it possible that you need to configure secure store services to allow an InfoPath form to be used using REST connection? (Again I need a bit more details). This is done by creating an application ID in the secure store and setting the credentials to an account that has the ability to read user profiles in your environment

If anything I think these links should help in your situation. Let me know if it does. Please find below:

- https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/982250
- http://www.sharepointalex.co.uk/index.php/2009/12/opening-infopath-form-in-sharepoint-requested-registry-access-is-not-allowed/

Comment: I've configured CA pretty much [as standard] (http://i.imgur.com/3I3T4sZ.png)
As for SSSA, I've no idea - In the SSS in CA I get `There are no Secure Store Target Applications in this Secure Store Service Application. You can create a new Target Application from the Manage Target Applications group in the Edit ribbon group.`